# Add require more information to approval flow

Tags: flow, power-automate

I am trying to write a simple approval flow on a SharePoint list. The standard approval is Approve/Reject but want to add a third option 'more information required' which triggers an email to the requestor clarifying what needs to be added. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom approval responses by setting **Approval type** to **Custom Responses**:

[image]

You can then send an email if the Need more information option is clicked:

[image]